# Terraform, ecs service creation fails when using a configured IAM policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, configuration, cloud-computing, amazon-iam, terraform

Using Terraform, ecs service creation fails when using a configured IAM policy.

```
Error applying plan:

1 error(s) occurred:

* aws_ecs_service.beatthemarket_service: InvalidParameterException: Unable to assume role and validate the listeners configured on your load balancer.  Please verify the role being passed has the proper permissions.
    status code: 400, request id: ba3a3fb8-0972-11e6-a877-954fd57ba1a9
```

This seems to correspond with [this issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/2869).
But I can’t seem to fix it, even after adding [a policy](https://github.com/twashing/beatthemarket/blob/master/aws.tf#L41-L77). I also don't think this is a timing issue, as the role already exists , after trying to `terraform apply` several times.

So far I just have an IAM **role**, **policy**, an **ELB**, and ECS **cluster**, **service** and **task definition**. Do I need anything else, like an **Autoscaling group**, **Launch configuration**, **Instance profile** or **Security group**?

Is there anything obvious missing, that explains why the service can't accept the role I've configured? The role seems to have all the correct permissions.

```
resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "beatthemarket" {
  name = "beatthemarket"
  role = "${aws_iam_role.beatthemarket.id}"
  policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
        "ec2:*",
        "ecs:*",
        "iam:*",
        "elasticloadbalancing:*"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Turns out I needed to set the service to ***ecs.amazonaws.com*** and not ***ec2.amazonaws.com*** in my *aws_iam_role*. I'd tried this before, but didn't specify sufficient in the *aws_iam_role_policy* . It's very much like [this issue](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=623824) on the AWS forums.

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "beatthemarket" {
    name = "beatthemarket"
    assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "ecs.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Sid": ""
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}
```

For future referencing, hope this helps someone.